# Puppet file type

Tags: puppet

I am testing puppet "file" type. I have added a simple manifests as following

```
root@pk121:/etc/puppet/manifests# cat site.pp
file { '/tmp/puppettest' :  
        source => "pk121.domain:///files/f1.txt",
 }
```

Try to apply on master, but getting following error

```
root@pk121:/etc/puppet/manifests# puppet apply site.pp
Notice: Compiled catalog for pk121.domain in environment production in 0.17 seconds
Error: Validation of File[/tmp/puppettest] failed: You cannot specify more than one of content, source, target at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:12
Wrapped exception:
You cannot specify more than one of content, source, target

root@pk121:/etc/puppet/manifests# ls -al ../files/f1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19 Mar 25 14:52 ../files/f1.txt
```

Edit

It is working fine locally, but still I am not able to sync f1.txt on agent, following is new configuration on master

```
root@pk121:/etc/puppet/environments/production/manifests# vi site.pp
    node default {
    file { '/tmp/puppettest' :
            source => "pk121.domain:///files/f1.txt",
     }
    }
```

Agent

```
root@hire:~# puppet agent --test
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Info: Caching catalog for hire.domain
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter source failed on File[/tmp/puppettest]: Cannot use URLs of type 'pk121.domain' as source for fileserving at /etc/puppet/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:3
Wrapped exception:
Cannot use URLs of type 'pk121.domain' as source for fileserving
```

Please let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 1):

Your [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier) is malformed and tries to use your node FQDN as an address schema.

Try just using the vanilla

```
puppet:///files/f1.txt
```

When using `puppet apply` on a local system, you could conceivably also just sync files from one disk location to another.

```
source => 'file:///etc/puppet/files/f1.txt'
```

or

```
source => '/etc/puppet/files/f1.txt'
```

Comment: pk121.domian is my master, i have try to use pk121 and pk121.domain, but both give me same error.

Comment: Yes, but your URI cannot work, just as you cannot reach google via `google.com://www`.

Comment: So what can i use, i cannot see any other option in document.

Comment: Please try the URI **from the answer**.